# What are SHAP loss values?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, shapley-value

Could anybody give a simple explanation of SHAP loss values? Perhaps with an example?

(I googled it but didn't find a lot and the things I found were not very clear... at least not to me)

Comment: Following is an awesome presentation from Scott. I highly recommend watching it all, but regarding your question, skip to 1:04:30
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-c8tIgchu0